# casting double * to complex*

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to cast double * to complex* .
I just have an example of a 2x2 matrix D (double) and i want to cast it as complex (C):

```
typedef complex<double> dcmplx;

 int main() {

   dcmplx *C;
   double *D;
   int N=2;

   D=new double[N*N];
   C=new dcmplx[N*N];
   *C=static_cast<dcmplx>(*D);

   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
      D[i*N+j]=i+j;
     }
   }


    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
      cout <<D[i*N+j]<<"\t";
     }
     cout <<"\n";
   }


   cout <<"\n\n";
   cout <<"Complex\n";
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
     for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
      cout <<C[i*N+j]<<"\t";
     }
     cout <<"\n";
   }


  return 0; 

 }
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you check a [`std::complex` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), pay close attention to the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%3D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the `std::complex<double>` and `double` are incompatible types therefore the casting via `static_cast` is not possible.

You can use available standard operators for `std::complex` to do conversions, 
have a look here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/operators/

A dummy example of conversion find below, this is just an example find an elegant solutions with `std::copy` or might be with other STL algorithms ! I'll never use such a code in my final source code :)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
{
   *C = *D;   
   D++;
   C++;
}
```

And finally if the two types were somehow compatible you have to do the casting of the pointers correctly like this.

`C = static_cast<dcmplx*>(D);`

---

**UPDATE** : Prepared a good example for you, enjoy :)

```
   std::vector< std::complex<double> > C (N*N);
   double* D = new double[N*N];
   // initialization of D's elements
   C.assign(D, D + N*N);
```

Comment: :It gives error: invalid static_cast from type ‘double*’ to type ‘dcmplx*

Comment: :How this would fit to my example?Can you make an example?Thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer, its just an example, but I would NOT use it in my final source codes, find more elegant solution with STL algorithms

Comment: @demius:Ok,in order to use copy I should use vectors?And it is a heavy operation?Because I tried to use copy but I am not sure how to define for example D.begin().

Comment: @George well implemented a good example for you, check the updated answer, enjoy :)

Comment: @George if you find the solution good for you, you can accept the answer as a solution :)

Comment: :Yes,of course!Just checking :) .If I want to fill some elements to C.real() for example what syntax should I use?Thank you very much (accepted and upvoted)!

Comment: Thanks, I think the plane assignment like this `mycomplex = 10.0` sets exactly the `mycomplex.real` to `10.0`

Comment: :Using this" C.assign(D, D + N*N); " assigns all the real values only to the C array.How can I assign imag values?Because C.imag()..is not accepted .

Comment: How are you going to initialize with a single double value both real and imaginary parts of the complex type, even from mathematical point of view it is tricky ? Your questions states that you have a double value with which you are going to initialize the complex value, so you have to decide what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

since c++11, you can cast a complex array to a double array,
see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

So this is possible:

`std::complex<double> a[10];
double *b  = reinterpret_cast<double *>(a);`

it works with vectors too:

`std::vector<std::complex<double>> a(10);
double *b = reinterpret_cast<double *>(a.data());`

It's very handy.

Answer (score 1):

`*D` is not an array, it's a `double` - the first element of the block that `D` points to.

In the same way, `*C` isn't an array either.

What you're doing is assigning `D[0]` to `C[0]`. You don't need casting for that, as `complex` has a suitable assignment operator.

You can't cast `double*` to `std::complex<double>*` because the types pointed to are unrelated.

If you want to build an array of `complex<double>` from an array of `double`, I think the simplest way is to use `std::copy`.
If you can't do that, use a loop and assign element by element.

You should also look into using `std::vector` instead of manual memory management.