# Casting device-side complex * to double * or float * for cublas

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust, cublas

### Problem

Is it safe to cast a `complex *` to a `float *` or `double *` pointer using `reinterpret_cast()`

```
thrust::complex<float> *devicePtr; // only to show type, devicePtr otherwise lives in an object
/* OR */
float _Complex         *devicePtr;
/* OR */
std::complex<float>    *devicePtr;

cublasScnrm2(cublasv2handle,n,(cuComplex*)xarray,1,reinterpret_cast<float *>(obj->devicePtr));
```

If not, are there clever ways to solve this problem?

### Restrictions

- `obj` is a C struct (so no direct operator overloading possible)
- I cannot store `devicePtr` as a `float *` within `obj`
- `devicePtr` only ever holds a pointer to a single value. It may be relevant given the `reinterpret_cast` trickery but behind the scenes `devicePtr` is part of a pool:

```
static thrust::complex<float> *pool;
/* OR */
static float _Complex         *pool;
/* OR */
std::complex<float>           *pool;

void giveObjectDevicePtr(object obj)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i) {
    if (poolEntryIsFree(pool,i)) obj->devicePtr = pool+i;
  }
}
```

- The cublas call is made asynchronously on a stream, so copying the contents of `devicePtr` up to host and syncing stream to perform conversion is to be avoided.

  - Likewise, launching a micro kernel is also not ideal but perhaps unavoidable.

I have seen [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936466/casting-double-to-complex) about casting `double *` or `float *` to `complex *` but not many the other way around.

Comment: A note for clarity: the question you linked to is about `std::complex`, not `thrust::complex`. While compatibility with `std::complex` is intended, my understanding is that `reinterpret_cast`s are rather poorly specified, making concrete guarantees quite difficult.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is because I forgot to add in the question that `thrust::complex` can also possibly be `std::complex`, I'll edit the question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Underneath the hood, complex types usable in CUDA should generally be a struct of two values.  You can see what I mean by looking at the cuComplex.h header file, as one possible example.

Casting a pointer to such, to a pointer type consistent with the values in that struct, should generally be *less* risky than the other way around (the other way around has additional alignment requirements beyond the base type).

If you posit the type you are discussing, exactly, then I claim this question has nothing to do with CUDA, and is really just a c++ question.

If you do such a cast, then provide that to a cublas function, in the general case I think you're going to be computing over both real and imaginary components, which seems weird to me.  It should not be an issue for the case you have shown, however.

You also seem to have some confusion about where a device pointer lives:

> copying devicePtr up to host

Any device pointer usable in a CUBLAS call for recent versions of CUBLAS lives in host memory.

Comment: > "You also seem to have some confusion about where a device pointer lives:". By this I meant copying the contents of the device pointer up to the host, not the pointer itself. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, this should theoretically be possible, though it is not explicit.

If you were dealing with `std::complex<T>`, the answer would be a definitive "yes". According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex#Array-oriented_access), a pointer to a `std::complex<T>` array can be `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer to a `T` array, with the intuitive semantics. This is for compatibility with C's complex numbers.

Now `thrust::complex<T>`, [the documentation states](https://thrust.github.io/doc/structthrust_1_1complex.html), "It is functionally identical to it, but can also be used in device code which std::complex currently cannot." Whether or not "functionally identical" includes compatibility with C's complex types is not explicit. That said, the structure is laid out as one would expect `std::complex<T>` to be laid out, which means (in a practical sense) it's likely that such a cast will work just like for `std::complex<T>`.